# use rm to remove files and directories recursively

Tags: unix, maintenance, rm

is it possible to use rm to remove files and directories matching a pattern recursively without using other commands?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To directly answer your question, "no - you can't do what you describe with `rm`".

You ***can***, however, do it you combine it with `find`. Here's one of many ways you could do that:

```
 # search for everything in this tree, search for the file pattern, pipe to rm
 find . | grep <pattern> | xargs rm
```

For example, if you want to nuke all *~ files, you could so this:

```
 # the $ anchors the grep search to the last character on the line
 find . -type f | grep '~'$ | xargs rm
```

To expand from a comment[*](https://superuser.com/users/14827/chris-johnsen):

```
 # this will handle spaces of funky characters in file names
 find -type f -name '*~' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: IMO: This is the best answer because you can preview the files that will be deleted prior to them being deleted.

Comment: true - if you leave-out the last pipe, you'll get a list of everything first :)

Comment: @steven And yet, it didn't actually answer the poster question

Comment: so, my -1 to this one

Comment: May not directly answer the poster's question, but is the closest they will get to what they want.

Comment: A Dwarf, isn't that a little bit bitter for no reason ?

Comment: The user post a simple question. Can he do it with only the rm command? He didn't ask how he could do it. For all that matters he can know other ways he can do it. And yet, perfectly valid answers to his question had been downvoted for no clear reason. Why shouldn't I downvote an answer that makes no effort to answer the actual question?

Comment: the answer is "no - you can't do what you describe with `rm`". I showed him how he *could* do it if he wants to.

Comment: Please be very careful using `find | grep | xargs rm`. If there are files with spaces (or newlines), this will break (and depending on the filenames and where the spaces are) might delete stuff that you did not intend to delete. `find … -print0 | xargs -0 rm` will be much more robust. It will mean, however that you cannot use `grep` and must use `find`'s predicates to match and print0 only the desired files. warren's second example will be more robust as `find -type f -name '*~' -print0 | xargs -0 rm`.

Comment: @Chris - updated my answer

Comment: @warren after your update, removed my downvote

Comment: If you want a single command to do the job, make an alias using one of the find commands given.  Will fill in an answer for this later, if desired.

Comment: You don't need funkier characters than a space to kill your first examples, and potentially delete other files than what is wanted. I recommend you change them to at least use `xargs -d'\n'` to allow spaces. But the two first examples are trumped by your last example, so perhaps just skip them. They are slower and less reliable.

Answer (score 8):

"without using other commands"

No.

Comment: Nice answer illustrating the "strictly answer the initial question (at the risk of not being able to provide a solution)" vs. "provide a solution, even if it's not strictly matching to imposed restrictions" debate.

Comment: I only posted this as "A Dwarf" was complaining about the answer that actually provided a solution. Without using other commands there really is no way to do recursive **file** deletion that matches a pattern, just current-directory file/directory deletion.

Answer (score 3):

Using Bash, with `globstar` set, **yes**:

```
rm basedir/**/my*pattern*
```

Try it with e.g. `ls -1` first, before `rm` to list the files you match.

You set options through e.g. `shopt -s globstar`.

---

Alternatively, a shorter `find` variant:

```
find -type f -name 'my*pattern*' -delete
```

or for GNU `find`:

```
find -type f -name 'my*pattern*' -exec rm {} +
```

or another alternative for non-GNU `find` (a bit slower):

```
find -type f -name 'my*pattern*' -exec rm {} \;
```

---

To also remove directories, as you ask for: just change `rm` into `rm -r` in the above commands and skip matching on only `-type f` in the `find` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I would have asuumed " rm -rf " where  is a combination of file names, and matching patterns such as * and ? etc (eg todays_log_2009????.log) . That will start from current Dir and work down recursively removing files that macth that pattern.

Comment: This won't work because the pattern is expanded by the shell in the current directory.  If quoted, the pattern becomes a filename with special characters in it.  e.g. to delete the file [, one could write rm '[' .  The pattern simply loses its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **zsh(1)**, turn on "extended globbing" with `setopt extendedglob` in .zshrc. Prefixing the pattern with '**/' will then delete recursively:

% rm -rf **/< pattern >

However, if there are *a lot* of files to delete you should resort to **find(1)** with **xargs(1)** or -exec, and I also recommend doing that in shell scripts.